# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory writing in a file in home directory

Tags: python

I have this code below to store some text in a file ~/.boto that is in home directory.

But Im getting this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.boto'
```

This is the code:

```
file = open("~/.boto") 
file.write("test")
file.close()
```

Comment: Tilde expansions doesn't work in `open()` command.
You must be specifying the complete path

Comment: Also, you have to `open` file for writing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use os.path.expanduser and open for writing with `w`:

```
import  os

# with will automatically close your file
with open(os.path.expanduser("~/.boto"),"w") as f:
    f.write("test") # write to file
```

**os.path.expanduser(path)**

> On Unix and Windows, return the argument with an initial component of ~ or ~user replaced by that user‘s home directory.
>
> On Unix, an initial ~ is replaced by the environment variable HOME if it is set; otherwise the current user’s home directory is looked up in the password directory through the built-in module pwd. An initial ~user is looked up directly in the password directory.
>
> On Windows, HOME and USERPROFILE will be used if set, otherwise a combination of HOMEPATH and HOMEDRIVE will be used. An initial ~user is handled by stripping the last directory component from the created user path derived above.
>
> If the expansion fails or if the path does not begin with a tilde, the path is returned unchanged.

```
In [17]: open("~/foo.py")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e9eb7789ac68> in <module>()
----> 1 open("~/foo.py")

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/foo.py'

In [18]: open(os.path.expanduser("~/foo.py"))
Out[18]: <open file '/home/padraic/foo.py', mode 'r' at 0x7f452d16e4b0>
```

By default a file is only open for reading, if you want to open for writing you need to use `w`, f you want to open for reading and writing use `r+` or to append use `a`.

If you have content in the file then `w` is going to **overwrite**, if you are trying to add to the file then use `a`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Now I can open the file for writing as you said, but then for write how can I do?

Comment: This part: file.write("test")

Comment: @techman, no prob, just make sure you don't overwrite files with content by using `w`, only use w to create files or overwrite existing

Answer (score 3):

Tilde expansions doesn't work inside `open()`. So python won't be able to expand `~` to `/home/user`

A solution would be to read `HOME` environmental variable using [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

```
import os

home = os.environ['HOME']
file = open( home + "/.boto", "w") 
file.write("test")
file.close()
```

**OR**

Using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) and [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

```
>>> import os
>>> filename = ".boto"
>>> os.path.join( os.environ['HOME'],  filename)
/home/user/.boto
```

Comment: Also, `os.path.join` instead of hardcoding the `/`

Comment: @WilliamPursell That's neat. I have updated my answer. Thank you for pointing out

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but Im getting an error: IOError: File not open for writing in file.write("test")

Comment: @techman You must be specifiying the mode as `writing` as `file = open( home + "/.boto", "w") `. Sorry for the typo. This ensures that the file is opened in `writing` mode

Comment: @techman Even after correcting the statement as `file = open( home + "/.boto", "w") ` ?