# Python with open doesn't create new file

Tags: python, file-handling, python-os

I'm working on a python project in which I need to create a new JSON file with a JSON object.

Here's what I have tried:

```
data = {
    'uid': userId,
    'description': description,
    'inputs': inputs,
    'outputs': outputs,
    'ex_inputs': example_input,
    'ex_outputs': example_output,
    'miscs': misc
}
print(data)
# Writing Finalized JSON description files
with open('finalized/description_' + str(fid) + '.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data))
```

I need the name of file as **description_FID.json** where FID is an integer value comes from HTML form.I have created an empty directory as **finalized** but it doesn't create the file in this directory.

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: operating system?

Comment: I’m using the OS X

Comment: Try with complete path

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30151425/3287355

Comment: Please post your trace back.

Comment: Try with the complete path and check whether that directory has write permission.